# How do i get single value from first table cell of particular column

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I want to set eurvalue variable equal to the value of the first cell from AvailableMoney table , column EUR
I have tried this

```
float eurvalue;
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=C:\Users\FluksikartoN\Documents\BFDB.sdf;Password=Corocoro93!";
            string sql = "SELECT EUR FROM AvailableMoney";
            using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    eurvalue = (float)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valueeur", value);                   
                   // cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            label2.Text = eurvalue.ToString();
```

Comment: And what is your result? This should work and `ExecuteScalar` is superior to `ExecuteReader` in your case.

Comment: eurvalue = (float)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); error : Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Use `object` instead of `float` temporarily to see if your result is null or something not convertable to `float`.

Comment: can you create solution for it i dont understand how object can get float value and then display it in label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all about robust error and null checking.

Incidentally, `float` is generally a poor data type for currency/money because it loses precision. I don't know what SQL Server CE offers but use a decimal type instead if you can.

```
using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, conn))
{
   object val = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   if(val != null) 
   {
      if(float.TryParse(val.ToString(), out eurvalue))
      {
         label2.Text = eurvalue.ToString();
      }
   }       
}
```

Comment: so you say the float is the problem if i change it to real will it work

Comment: No, the use of the float data type is not your programming problem. I'm just saying as a side-note that it is less appropriate to represent money. Same thing with Real. Use the `money` type if it is not too late to change your schema.

Comment: I understand but i want to save only numbers into database then i retrieve them and convert them to whatever i want but maybe you are right im really new to c# and sql but thanks anyway your code works

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ExecuteReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t066c6sf(v=vs.100).aspx) instead `ExecuteScalar`. The method `ExecuteReader` returns a [`SqlCeDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedatareader(v=vs.100).aspx) which allows reading a forward-only stream of rows from a data source.

```
        float eurvalue = 0.0f;
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=C:\Users\FluksikartoN\Documents\BFDB.sdf;Password=Corocoro93!";
        string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 EUR FROM AvailableMoney";
        using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if(reader.Read())
                    {
                        eurvalue = reader.GetFloat(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        label2.Text = eurvalue.ToString();
```

Comment: strange thing eurvalue error 'Use of unassigned local variable'

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov, you should initialize the variable `eurvalue`, I have updated answer.

Comment: Error 1 Literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type 'float'; use an 'F' suffix to create a literal of this type

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov, sorry, I have updated answer. Try now.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, I disagree that `ExecuteReader` is better than `ExecuteScalar`. It is a different problem.

Comment: gives me Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov, what type of a field `EUR` in the table `AvailableMoney`?